# Assign date to Dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, warnings

Trying to assign a date to a column in a DataFrame.

Assigning in the following way gives an error

```
for date in sorted(list(set(dates))):
    df.loc[:, 'DATE'] = date

Error Cannot set a frame with no defined index and a scalar
```

Okay, fine:

```
for date in sorted(list(set(dates))):
    df['DATE'] = date

Warning: A value is truing to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame, try using .loc ...
```

What is it exactly that python prefers I do to not avoid an Error with a Warning instead?

Many thanks!

Comment: this is applicable outside of a loop as well, but thank you

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure that `len(sorted(list(set(dates)))) == len(df)` then you can simply do:

```
df['DATE'] = sorted(list(set(dates)))
```